MS Purview DLP Approval / Rejection on Mac
I recently tried to use a feature in MSFT Purview DLP that allows emails containing X amount of PII (defined in the policy) to be forwarded to the users manager for approval. I've gotten the functionality to work and when the users manager opens the email on a Windows device, or in Outlook on the Web, they get an Approve and Reject button in the top left corner of the email. On Mac devices with Outlook, they get nothing. I've tried both Classic Outlook and New Outlook but the behavior is the same. I opened up a case with MSFT but my expectations are low and they're slow. Has anyone come across this issue and resolved? Appreciate any assistance anyone can provide. Thx! Rich

It sounds like you're encountering a known limitation with Outlook for Mac. Currently, the Approve and Reject buttons for DLP policy actions are not supported in Outlook for Mac. This issue affects both the Classic and New Outlook versions on Mac.
As a workaround, you can advise users to use Outlook on the Web (OWA) for these actions, as the functionality works there.

Thanks Jake. Appreciate the response. I was going to try to create a flow in Teams that allows for approval but it isn't very straightforward.

Creating an approval flow in Microsoft Teams is a bit complicated, but you can refer to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/teams/native-approvals-in-teams
